# Add to / modify request.env in a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, environment-variables

How could I modify request.env in a controller? I want to do something like this:

```
request.env["newkey"] = content
```

And then in the next controller, that I redirect_to from the one that sets the env, I want to use request.env["newkey"] to access the content.

So how would I modify request.env?

Answer (score 2):

`request.env["newkey"] = content` does work in adding the new key to the `request.env` object.

However, that doesn't help in what you are trying to accomplish because on redirecting, it is a new request, and the `request.env` object is recreated. The `newkey` set in the previous request is lost.

What you need to use is [rails flash.](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Flash.html)

> The flash provides a way to pass temporary primitive-types (String, Array, Hash) between actions. Anything you place in the flash will be exposed to the very next action and then cleared out.

Set the value in the first method as follows:

```
def <first_method>
  ...
  flash[:newkey] = params[:number]
  redirect_to ...
end
```

Then it can be accessed in the redirected_to method as follows:

```
 def <redirected_to_method>
   ...
   new_key_val = flash[:newkey]
   ...
 end
```

Comment: I'm using Omniauth, on callback it uses the request.env['omniauth.auth'] variable, I would like to fill that very same variable. Is this not possible at all? I am also not using a primitive type, I'm passing an instance on OmniAuth::AuthHash.

Comment: If you are expecting the `request.env['omniauth.auth'] ` to be available in the new method, then you should figure out why it is not there, rather than try to force it to be there.

Comment: Is there an alternative to flash that can handle non primitive data types?